# IE9 Broken Video Tag

Tags: css, html

This is the code I Used.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="something.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.

</video>
```

It shows a black box with red X in the center. Someone suggested to simply added the following line to my .htaccess to make .MP4 work in IE9:AddType video/mp4 .mp4 
The only problem is I Dont Know What .htaccess Is And I Dont Think my page is on (or I dont Have One).

Please Help Me Thanx

Comment: Depending on the webserver you use, you might need to add "missing" MIME types, or the server won't serve them. Are you using Apache or IIS?

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) for info on HTML5 videos. Note that Internet Explorer requires alternate video formats in addition to the ones you already have. Also, click the "Check" button there - this will tell you if IE9 supports the video tag - it could well be that it does not.

About the .htaccess - ignore that for now. Odds are, if you don't know what it is, you haven't overwritten the defaults and you should be all right.

And finally, does the file exist at './something.mp4'? If so, do you have a video player plugin that you know works? This could also be the issue.